# ORA-01843: not a valid month : TO_DATE('12-JUN-02','DD-MON-YY')

Tags: sql, oracle

I've faced a problem during insert. Here is the problem:

```
INSERT INTO SALES_ORDER_A4 (ORDERNO , CLIENTNO , ORDERDATE , DELYADDR , SALESMANNO , DELYTYPE , BILLYN , DELYDATE, ORDERSTATUS)
SELECT 'O19008' ,
       'C00005' ,
       to_date('24-MAY-02','DD-MON-YY'),
       'Delhi' ,
       'S00004' ,
       'F' ,
       'N' ,
       to_date('26-MAY-02','DD-MON-YY') ,
       'In Process'
FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'O19001' ,
       'C00001' ,
       to_date('12-JUN-02','DD-MON-YY') ,
       'Delhi' ,
       'S00001' ,
       'F' ,
       'N' ,
       to_date('20-JUN-02','DD-MON-YY') ,
       'In Process'
FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'O19002' ,
       'C00002' ,
       to_date('25-JUN-02','DD-MON-YY'),
       'Delhi' ,
       'S00002' ,
       'P' ,
       'N' ,
       to_date('27-JUL-02','DD-MON-YY') ,
       'Cancelled'
FROM DUAL
```

---

I have faced an exception at  phrase *to_date('12-JUN-02','DD-MON-YY' )* that:

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

My instructor can not find the problem, what is the problem here?

Comment: What does `select to_char(TO_DATE('25.06.2002','DD.MM.YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY' ) from dual` returns? Probably, nls_lang is not set to english.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_options067.htm#OLADM408

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is mostly because `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` is not set correctly.

First check the value by:

```
select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter like '%DATE%'
```

If the value of `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` is not `American` then change it by:

```
alter session set nls_date_language='American';
```

And try again.

Comment: what to do to execute the statement without changing the nls_date_language value?